# Javascript with Smarty & Google Maps API

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps, smarty

Being the absolute java newbie that I am, I've tortured myself getting to where I am. But, I did it. And, I couldn't be more happy! But... I have one last and final issue.

I'm using Smarty. Smarty writes the dynamic javascript for me to load my map's markers.

I need to include my header and footer .tpl files. My header.tpl has a `<head>` and `<body>` but my maps code depends on the `<head>` and `<body>` being where it is.

The  part of the code is the problem.

I absolutely can not figure out how to execute my javascript without this "onload" code. Can someone give me a tip?

All I really need is to know how to launch my javascript code without it being dependant on the `<body>` tag.

Here's my code and thank you SO MUCH in advance!

```
{*

{include file="header.tpl"}
<h3 class="titlehdr">Book Buyers - Accounts Map</h3>
{if $userlevel == 5}
    <p>Admin User</p>
{/if}
Hello, {$name}!
<br><br>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 50% }
  body { height: 50%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 50% }
</style>
*}



<br><br>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{foreach from=$getMap key=k item=v}
    var buyer{$k} = new google.maps.LatLng
    {foreach from=$v key=k item=latlng}
        {if $k == "lat"}
            ( {$latlng} ,
        {else}
            {$latlng} ); 
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}

var marker;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: warehouse
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: buyer5
  });
{foreach from=$getMap key=k item=v}
    marker{$k} = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: buyer{$k}
    });
{/foreach}

}

</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%; height:70%"></div>


{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JQuery, all you need to do is call that code in `<script></script>` tags. Here's how you can call your code when document is loaded into the browser and is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

         //Your code supposed to be called, goes here.

    });
</script>
```

While `<script>` tag works even if wrote in any part of the document, if you're using "great" browsers, you know what I mean ;-). But its not a good practice to have those tags at any random place on the page, as this can be a compatibility issues. So keep the code within `<head></head>` tags of your page.

And for JQuery, you can either download latest stable release from its website, or simply add the following line in your `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```